# Monitoring CPU usage of each services

Tags: cpu-usage, windows-services

With tools like Process Hacker it's easy to find which Windows Services are being executed by an instance of svchost.exe, but this doesn't provide many informations.

Is there any way to find the CPU usage for each service?

[image]

Comment: I don't understand your question. ProcessHacker shows cpu usage for each instance of svchost.exe on my WInbdows 7 system.

Comment: since Windows 10 Creators Update the services [are isolated and you can easily see which service causes issues](https://superuser.com/a/1212692/174557) and with [ProcessExplorer/Hacker you can see which service causes cpu usage](https://superuser.com/a/1135860/174557)

Answer (score 2):

**Using Resource Monitor**

see https://serverfault.com/questions/27718/how-do-i-track-cpu-utilization-for-window-services

[image]

**Using Process Hacker:**

On the Services tab, no it doesn't give CPU details per service.

On the Processes tab, the tooltips on svchost.exe list the services run by that instance of svchost. I don't think it is possible to separate out the CPU usage of one service from another if they are both running under the same svchost.

[image]

Also, you can use the search field on the processes tab and type a name of a service to find which svchost it is running under.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but so there is no way to understand which service is consuming the CPU?