# Which service is run by svchost

Tags: windows-7, performance-monitor, perfmon

I am currently monitoring a system with perfmon and logging the following counters:

- `\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time` (overall usage)
- `\Process(*)\% Processor Time` (usage per process).

I can later see, that `svchost.exe#785` (`785` is an example here) was responsible for a CPU spike. Is there any way to see, which service that instance of `svchost.exe` had been busy with? Do I have to log anything in addition?

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/1135860/174557 you also run into the [WindowsUpdate scan issue](https://superuser.com/a/996072/174557)

Comment: How can you say that? I have searching for updates turned off...

Comment: because this is a known issue for Windows 7. use ProcessExplorer to see which service causes it

Comment: So there is no way to log which service runs in which executable?

Comment: no, in Windows 10 v1703 the services get now [hosted separately](https://superuser.com/a/1212692/174557)